# how can I add user managed identity to the existing aks cluster agent pools (vmss)?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-managed-identity

I have tried every possible way including change the cluster resource definition as shown below and rollout (incremental) but get "Cluster's 'identity.Type' should not be changed. Your cluster will not work properly." , I tried also to use identityProfile. Nothing works. How can I add a user managed identities to the underlying vmss in aks?

"identity": {
"type": "SystemAssigned, UserAssigned",
"userAssignedIdentities": {
"[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', 'my-test-identity')]":{}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

To add a user managed identity to the existing AKS cluster agent pools, update the cluster resource definition to include the user-assigned managed identity as below:

```
az aks update --resource-group <YourRG> --name <ClusterName> --assign-identity <resourceIDOfIdentity> --enable-managed-identity
```

***Output***
[image]

[image]

after that update the agent pool VMSS in order to use the user-assigned managed identity. For that, you can use the [az vmss identity assign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vmss/identity?view=azure-cli-latest) command to assign the managed identity to the VMSS.

```
 az vmss identity assign -g "<MC_RG_Name>" -n "<VMSSName>" --identities "<Your_Managed_Identity_resource_ID>"
```

***output***
[image]

You can verify the same using:

```
az vmss identity show --resource-group "<MC_RG_Name>" --name "<VMSSName>"
```

***output***

[image]

Reference Document:

[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vmss/identity?view=azure-cli-latest)

[Managed Identity on AKS](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/aks/use-managed-identity.md)

Comment: That is not a problem. I use arm template to deploy aks and I have system assigned identity is one and others add on/ resources have added user managed identities. My question is how can I add additional user managed identity, using arm template , and still keep existing system managed identity, plus user managed identities on the vmss

Comment: what are you trying to do by using a different identity for the vmss ?